# Physics-based/Polynomial Animation with Box2d (Java)

Tags: java, animation, box2d, collision, polynomials

I'm creating a 2d game using the Java version of Box2d.

I know that the engine is generally paired with a separate library to handle animation, but I'm looking for something simple, with a more rustic feel, so I'm considering handling the animation from scratch.

The animation I am trying to create is something for the collision of two objects.

I'm using openGl to handle the graphics, and I pretty much have everything set up with the fps and rendering, it's just a matter of tweaking the frames to make it look smooth.

I tried bliting images of some things that I drew myself and it looked atrocious. I think the main problem is that the animation frame images are not linked to the physics forces and so they don't blend well.

What I want to try next is a sort 'spark effect' using a small number of pixels that sort of resemble 'dust' exploding off of the colliding images. If you've ever played dxball, you may recall a similar effect when the ball collided with the paddle at high speed.

[image: the animation]

As you can see in the above image, the principles are fairly simple. I figure by creating a set of small bodies with fixtures, I can use the box2d engine to produce this effect. I already have code that grabs the point of collision for all bodies, and am familiar enough with parabolic functions that I pretty sure I can create the force direction.

I'm just not sure if there is a better way of doing this, or how to apply a polynomial function to a body like in the image.

Does anybody know how to achieve this functionality with box2d? Any built in methods or documentation that would be helpful?

As a point of reference, the following snippet of code demonstrates the drawing of a small, red box on all of the collision points.

```
   for(Vec2 point : listener.worldmanifold.points){

        glPushMatrix();
        newpos = point.mul(30);
        glTranslatef(newpos.x, newpos.y, 0);

        glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glRectf(-2, -2, 2, 2);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
```